# Object Oriented Programming: Problem with self in the Constructor, Python 3

Tags: python, oop, constructor, spyder, blackjack

I'm currently trying to learn python and am attempting to understand classes and I've ran into a weird problem.

```
class card:
    def __init__(self, s, num, name):
        self.suit = s
        self.number = num
        self.name = name

class aceCard(card):
    def __init__(s):
        card.__init__(s, 0, "ace of " + s)
        value1 = 1
        valye11 = 11

class numCard(card):
    def __init__(s, num):
        name = num, " of ", s
        card.__init__(s, num, name)
        value = num

class faceCard(card):
    def __init__(s, num):
        if (num == 11):
            name = "jack of " + s
        elif (num == 12):
            name = "queen of " + s
        elif (num == 13):
            name = "king of " + s
        card.__init__(s, num, name)
        value = 10

class suits:
    cards = []
    def __init__(s):
        cards = [aceCard.__init__(s)]
        n = 1
        while n<11:
            cards.append(numCard.__init__(s, n))
            n+=1
        while n<14 and n>10:
            cards.append(faceCard.__init__(s, n))
            n+=1
        
class deck:
    adeck = []
    def __init__():
        adeck = [suits.__init__("clubs"), suits.__init__("diamonds"), suits.__init__("hearts"), suits.__init__("spades")]
    
    def print():
        for suitses in adeck:
            for cardses in suitses:
                print(cardses.name)
            
                
        
deck1 = deck.__init__()
deck1.print()
```

The error message from the Spyder IDE is

```
runfile('###', wdir='###')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "###", line 55, in <module>
    deck1 = deck.__init__()

  File "###", line 46, in __init__
    adeck = [suits.__init__("clubs"), suits.__init__("diamonds"), suits.__init__("hearts"), suits.__init__("spades")]

  File "###", line 34, in __init__
    cards = [aceCard.__init__(s)]

  File "###", line 10, in __init__
    card.__init__(s, 0, "ace of " + s)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

The part that confuses me is the fact that the interpreter expects self to be used like a normal parameter rather than being skipped over. Pls help.

Edit:
My question doesn't seem to be fixed by anything I search. My problem is that everything I'm checking to teach me tells me to use as self as a parameter and in the code I'm to use it like "this" in java. However, when I call the constructor, I am to ignore self as the first parameter and use the succeeding ones only. What is the problem there that I'm missing?

Comment: Where are you confused?  The error message is quite clear.  You defined `card.__init__` as requiring four arguments (refer to your code).  When you called the code in line 10, you supplied only three arguments.  You have to make up your mind how the initialization method will work.

Comment: Also note that this is *not* the usual way to create a class instance: in each of these calls, you create a `card` and ignore the object you created -- you have no way to refer to that card again.  I recommend that (1) you repeat your tutorial(s) on classes and instances to learn common usage; (2) you use better programming practices: test small bits of your code to make sure that they work, before writing more code.  You've posted about 50 lines of code with several programming irregularities to fix.

Comment: @Prune any good recommendation for  "tutorial(s) on classes and instances to learn common usage"

Comment: @Prune you would actually call the parent initialisation with 3 arguments, but python uses [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for this to first construct the parent instance (using [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)) and then supply that instance to `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues with your code, but the root of you problem is that you don't know how to construct parent instances.

Python uses [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) to do this:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, s, num, name):
        self.suit = s
        self.number = num
        self.name = name

class AceCard(Card):
    def __init__(self, s):
        super().__init__(s, 0, "ace of " + s)
        # This does nothing. Just creates local variables which are discarded
        # once the function ends.
        value1 = 1
        valye11 = 11
```

I can recommend [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) as a good intro to Python's OOP implementation.